# is there a way to display nearing DueDate client when there is 5 days left? VB.net mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image: This the tables..]

I want to display the following below in the client status to the nearly due date when there is only 5 days left before their duedate..
I search a lot from internet and and still Im at lost..
and I tried different query and still not getting what I wanted

this is my code:

```vb
Public Sub fillNearDue()

    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Dim todayD As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM")
    connect()

    'Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT *, IF(now() > dueDate, 'EXPIRED', '') AS Expiry FROM payments", con)
    '  Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("if(dueDate-now()*-1 <= 5, 'EXPIRED','') AS Expiry FROM payments", con)
    'Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT *  FROM payments WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,'dueDate',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 1", con)
    Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("Select *, DATEDIFF(dueDate,now() ) as Days from payments where DATEDIFF( dueDate,now()) < 5", con)
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd1


    sda.Fill(dbDataSet)
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
    GRDnearDue.DataSource = bSource

    disconnect()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select will give you all the pymenst due in 5 days but also all the payments that are already due today. So reduce the DATEDIFF days to only positive numbers and  you will get all the data you want.

Try

```
Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("Select *, DATEDIFF(dueDate,now() ) as Days 
     from payments where DATEDIFF( dueDate,now()) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF( dueDate,now()) <= 5", con)
```

You could add to the where Clause all already paid payments, that would reduce the number of rows even further

Comment: Thank you so much @nbk and I now understand how that code works